# Display ItemsControl as a single datagrid row

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I have the following ItemsControl that I use to display a collection of viewModels.

```
<Border>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModel.MyCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="20"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     </ItemsControl>
</Border>
```

And the code behind is:

```
MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();

foreach(var model in MyModelList)
{
    var myViewModel = new ViewModel(model);

    MyCollection.Add(myViewModel);
}
```

Now this works fine.  BUT now I want to not have an ItemsControl  because there are only ever two items that are going to be added to MyCollection ObservableCollection.

I want to add each of the two viewModels into their own column in a single row datagrid in order to display the grid columns differently. (For example when user clicks on one viewModel I want to change the datagird background for only that column)

How do I modify the above to do this?

Comment: Can you please suggest a code example with your DataGrid? I'm not sure the ItemsControl code helps in this case...

Comment: No I want to remove the ItemsControl.  I want to place one View model in datagrid row=0 column=0 and another ViewModel into datagrid row=0 column=1.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that holds the two view models:

```
public class RowOfViewModels
{
    public ViewModel ViewModelA { get; set; }
    public ViewModel ViewModelB { get; set; }
}
```

...and set or bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to collection that contains a single instance of this one:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = new List<RowOfViewModels>(1) { ViewModelA = new ViewModel(), ViewModelB = new ViewModel() };
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="1">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomePropertyOfViewModelA}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="2">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomePropertyOfViewModelB}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template for Cell in specific column (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502173/wpf-datagrid-binding-datagridcell-content)), for example:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="...">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```